# Multiple for loops using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have written my script which shown below, I have mentioned my expected out and also I have mentioned the error which i am getting. Can anyone help me?

Script:

```
for {set x 0} {$x <= 80} {incr x [expr {+20}]} {
    puts "pdb ./$x.a.pdb;"
    puts "pdb ./$x.b.pdb;"
    puts "pdb ./$x.ab.pdb;"
    for {set i 0} {$i < 15} {incr i} {
        puts "A$x = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect $i "all"]] >> 1.dat" }
    for {set j 1} {$j < 15} {incr j} {
        puts "B$x = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect $j "all"]] >> 1.dat"}
    for {set k 2} {$k < 15} {incr k} {
        puts "AB$x = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect $k "all"]] >>1.dat"}
}
```

Output which I get:

```
invalid command name "atomselect"
    while executing
"atomselect $i "all""
    ("for" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"for {set x 0} {$x <= 80} {incr x [expr {+20}]} {
    puts "pdb ./$x.a.pdb;"
    puts "pdb ./$x.b.pdb;"
    puts "pdb ./$x.ab.pdb;"
    for {set i 0} {$i < 15} {incr i..."
    (file "try.tcl" line 1)
```

Expected Output:

```
 pdb ./0.a.pdb;
 pdb ./0.b.pdb;
 pdb ./0.ab.pdb;
 A0 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 0 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 B0 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 1 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 AB0 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 2 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 pdb ./20.a.pdb;
 pdb ./20.b.pdb;
 pdb ./20.ab.pdb;
 A20 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 3 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 B20 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 4 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 AB20 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 5 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 pdb ./40.a.pdb;
 pdb ./40.b.pdb;
 pdb ./40.ab.pdb;
 A40 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 6 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 B40 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 7 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 AB40 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 8 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 pdb ./60.a.pdb;
 pdb ./60.b.pdb;
 pdb ./60.ab.pdb;
 A60 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 9 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 B60 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 10 "all"]] >> 1.dat
 AB60 = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect 11 "all"]] >> 1.dat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loops aren't the problem here: Square  brackets are Tcl's "command substitution" syntax (like backticks or `$(...)` in the shell). You need to escape the open square brackets (and the inner quotes)

```
puts "A$x = \[measure sasa 1.4 \[atomselect $i \"all\"]] >> 1.dat"
```

or use the `format` command

```
puts [format {A%d = [measure sasa 1.4 [atomselect %d "all"]] >> 1.dat} $x $i]
```

I used curly braces in the 2nd example to show Tcl's other, non-interpolating, quotes (like the shell's single quotes).